# Using Boolean in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that uses a boolean essentially I want my click() to be option  when I call my method. My code is as follows

```
    public void testBoolean(String Name,Boolean clickCheckbox){

            setPccName(Name);
            driver.findElement(By.id("testlocation")).sendKeys(getPccName());
            driver.findElement(By.id("testclick")).click());clickCheckbox;

    }
```

So when I call my method I should be able to set the name using the string name and then be able to decide if I want to click the checkbox. for example

```
    testBoolean("MyNameTest",true);
```

Comment: what is the deciding condition ? what is your challenge

Comment: Why do you have a statement of `clickCheckBox;` on its own? What do you expect that to do? Any reason for using `Boolean` rather than `boolean`?

Comment: by leaving clickCheckbox I'm hoping that the driver.findElement(By.id("testclick")).click()); will become optional. For example in my below test method testBoolean("MynameTest",true) will click the id. But if it was set to false it would not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are missing but one if-statement:

```
public void testBoolean(String Name, boolean clickCheckbox){
    if (clickCheckbox) {
        setPccName(Name);
        driver.findElement(By.id("testlocation")).sendKeys(getPccName());
        driver.findElement(By.id("testclick")).click());
    }
}
```

Or maybe you meant this:

```
public void testBoolean(String Name, boolean clickCheckbox){
    setPccName(Name);
    driver.findElement(By.id("testlocation")).sendKeys(getPccName());
    driver.findElement(By.id("testclick")).click());

    if (clickCheckbox) {
        clickCheckbox();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I changed `Boolean` into `boolean` as I saw no reason to use the object version.

Comment: @laune yeah I was editing it out but you beat me in my own game